# MIPS print integer without use any pseudoinstructions

Tags: assembly, mips

Here is what I did

```
num1:.word 1
num2:.word 2
.globl main
.text
main:
lui $t0,0x1001
addi $v0,$0,1  #set commend to print 
addi $s2,$0,5 # add 5 to $s2
sw $s2,4($t0) # store the val in word 2
addi $a0,$t0,4 # add 4 to t0 to start the second word 
syscall # print int
```

I want the value of s2 to be print however I got 268500996. Also , if i want to print word 1 and word 2 how to make each output  on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

`syscall` 1 [expects `$a0` to contain the value to print](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html), no the address of the value to print. So instead of:

```
sw $s2,4($t0) # store the val in word 2
addi $a0,$t0,4 # add 4 to t0 to start the second word
```

you should just do:

```
or $a0, $s2, $0  # $a0 = $s2
```

---

To print a newline you would print the characters 13 (Carriage Return) and 10 (Linefeed). You could do this either with `syscall` 4 (`print_string`) or two calls to `syscall` 11 (`print_character`).